# What is probability to get through to the value

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have data set of ints with values 1..10.

Before any sample is added to the dataset it can be observed for a period of time. During this period X can grow from 1 to 10 (**Note : it only grows in one directio through all values 1,2,3...10**).

**Once added it cant change**.

For example if you are observing next X currently being 3 that means it went throug 1 and 2 and it can stay as 3 till the moment it added to the dataset or it can go higher to 4, 5 .. up to 10.

I have count of each X value from the past. eg

```
X  Y (count of X in the past)
1  12
2  21
3  11
..
10 100
```

*I need to calculate probability of X which **hasnt been added to the dataset yet** to grow up to 10 (knowing that X cant go lower than the value it has at this particular moment).*

Obviously if the obeserved X is 10 at the moment it has 100% probability to grow to 10.

**EDIT:** (I am trying to explain the process). This is discrete process. Initial value of X is 1 always. Then it can move to 2 then 3 ... up to 10.

When value goes up it guaranteed makes it through each consequtive value (ie 10 goes though each - 1,2,3..9 then 10)

Process can stop at any time. There is no additional information on why value goes from X1 to X2. The process is completely random in that direction.

Comment: This looks very similar to a question you previously asked (that appears to have been deleted). I'm afraid this question is not much clearer than the first time you posted it. Some additional detail would increase the probability that you get a good answer - for example - Is this a markov chain? What parameterizes the jumps from one level to the next? In any case why not just use the empirical frequencies? For example, what proportion of $X$s that were 3s at one point eventually got to 10? That's your estimate of the probability.

Comment: > what proportion of X s that were 3s at one point eventually got to 10? That's your estimate of the probability <-- because all X going through each value consequentially 1,2,3...10 then any X = 10 went through 3 for sure, as well as through 4,5.. 9 etc... that has to be easy.

Comment: You've asked a very unclear question, and you certainly are not telling us the whole story. This makes it very hard to provide an answer. You would get better results if you explain what actual process is producing this data set, and what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You are right. I just dont know how to explain it.. However I found the answer. Empirically.. Probability I was looking for is Count(X10) / RunningBackwardSum(Xx)... **a.** calculate for X=3 running sum of counts for 10, 9, .. 3... Say RunningBackwardSum(X3) = 120.. **b.** count of X=10 is 100 in this example so **the probability that 3 will grow to 10 is 100/120 = 0.83 **

Comment: FYI: I didn't downvote. I downvoted the previous question you deleted, but I didn't want to bias your responses by starting you off negatively, so I refrained this time.

Comment: Also, re: "because all X going through each value consequentially 1,2,3...10 then any X = 10 went through 3 for sure" you interpreted my suggestion backwards. I suggested the proportion of all 3s that eventually get to 10. Not the proportion of all 10s that were once at 3. With the information you gave, this was the best suggestion I could give - I was not "yanking your chain" or trying to show "how clever I am". Relax and please maintain a respectful tone when you use this site.

Comment: 3s which become 10 equal sum(10s) as each 10 went through 3 in first place.

Comment: I don't know what "3s which become 10 equal sum(10s) as each 10 went through 3 in first place" means but what I was suggesting was (1) Calculate the number of points that pass through 3 at some point. Call that $n$. (2) Calculate the number of points that eventually reach 10. Call that $m$. (3) Calculate $m/n$. This estimates the probability that you eventually reach stage 10, given that you were in stage 3 at one point.

Comment: thank you Macro. that what I did (see my comment - 5th from top). if you write your comment as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can estimate these probabilities by using the observed relative frequencies. For example, if you want to calculate the probability that a point which passes through '3' eventually gets to '10', you could:

(1) Calculate the number of points that pass through 3 at some point. Call that $n$.

(2) Calculate the number of points that eventually reach 10 (this is a monotonically increasing random process, so this is strictly a subset of those that pass through '3'). Call that $m$.

(3) Calculate $m/n$. This estimates the probability that you eventually reach stage 10, given that you were in stage 3 at one point.

You could analogously estimate the probability that a point which passes through stage $x$ eventually reaches stage $y$ in the same way.